# Why is my variable returning a large negative number when dividing?

Tags: c, cs50, integer-division

I'm tackling the credit problem from cs50 and I'm baffled by the for loop on one section because I'm dividing a long integer **4003600000000014** by **100** and it returns a large negative number **-1685133312**.

Here is the actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    long int number;
    long int temp;
    do
    {
        number = get_long("Number: ");
    } while (number < 0);

    temp = number;
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 10; i <= number; i = 10)
    {
        number /= i;
        counter += 1;
    }
    printf("%i\n", counter);

    int product = 0;
    int divisor = 100;
    int modulo = 0;
    //printf("%li\n", (temp % 100) / 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < counter / 2; i++)
    {
        modulo = temp / divisor;
        divisor *= 100;
        product += (2 * (modulo % 10));
    }
    printf("%i\n", product);
}
```

Here is the portion where the division occurs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter / 2; i++)
    {
        modulo = temp / divisor;
        divisor *= 100;
        product += (2 * (modulo % 10));
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Edit: Thank you guys, I just needed to make modulo type long int.

Comment: Mixing `long` and `int` where you know the values exceed the limits of an `int` seems like a bad thing. Of course there's no guarantee `long` is 64-bit either. Hopefully you checked that on your platform. Credit card numbers are best handled as strings of digits anyway.

Comment: Hello @RetiredNinja, I'm currently using vscode specifically the one from cs50.dev. Is that relevant? I also tried running a simple code from another .c file directly dividing the long int from the int and getting the desired result.

I have thought of converting it to string but I thought I could make it work as int so I wanna try anyway.

Comment: `modulo` is not large enough to hold that result so you get a signed overflow which is undefined behavior. Make `modulo` a long`.

Comment: Thank you @RetiredNinja. That solved it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: There is no signed overflow, and the behavior is not undefined. In `temp / divisor`, `divisor` (100) is converted to `long int` to match `temp` (4,003,600,000,000,014), and then the division is performed in `long int`, producing 40,036,000,000,000. Then, to assign this to the `int` `modulo`, the value is converted to `int`. It is not representable in `int`, so C 2018 6.3.1.3 3 applies: “Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.”

Answer (score 6):

In `temp / divisor`, the value of `divisor`, 100, is converted to `long int` to match `temp`, which has value 4,003,600,000,000,014, and then the division is performed in `long int`, producing 40,036,000,000,000.

Then, to assign this to the `int` `modulo`, the value is converted to `int`. It is not representable in `int`, so C 2018 6.3.1.3 3 applies: “Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.”

If you are using GCC, [the conversion is defined to wrap modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Integers-implementation.html), where *N* is the width (number of value and sign bits) of the destination type. You apparently have a 32-bit `int`, so 40,036,000,000,000 is wrapped modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.

40,036,000,000,000 − 9,322•2<sup>32</sup> = −1,685,133,312, so that is the result.